# KeyError(f"None of [{key}] are in the [{axis_name}]") in Webscraper

Tags: python, html

I'm working on a webscraper, and testing it on Yelp. I get the following error whenever I run the code, and I can't figure out what is going wrong. I'm new to Selenium and Pandas, so not 100% sure what is going wrong here. Using Python 3.6, and am still relatively new to Python in general! I was basing this off the following example: https://websitescrapingtutorials.wordpress.com/2019/06/23/how-to-scrape-yelp/

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "webscraper.py", line 81, in <module>
    df = df[['Restaurant_Name', 'Phone_Number', 'Address', 'States', 'Category']]
  File "C:\Users\Dominick\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 2908, in __getitem__
    indexer = self.loc._get_listlike_indexer(key, axis=1, raise_missing=True)[1]
  File "C:\Users\Dominick\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py", line 1254, in _get_listlike_indexer
    self._validate_read_indexer(keyarr, indexer, axis, raise_missing=raise_missing)
  File "C:\Users\Dominick\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py", line 1298, in _validate_read_indexer
    raise KeyError(f"None of [{key}] are in the [{axis_name}]")
KeyError: "None of [Index(['Restaurant_Name', 'Phone_Number', 'Address', 'States', 'Category'], dtype='object')] are in the [columns]"
```

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import time
import pandas
 
#URL = This is the url of the yelp page that you are going to extract data from
 
URL = ('https://www.yelp.com/search?cflt=pizza&find_loc=Pittsburgh%2C+PA')
 
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(URL)
yelp_page_source_page1 = driver.page_source

final_data = []
 
soup = BeautifulSoup(yelp_page_source_page1,'html.parser')
all = soup.find_all('li',{'class':'lemon--li__373c0__1r9wz border-color--default__373c0__2oFDT'})

for data in all:
    info_scraped = {}
    try:
        base = data.find('h3',{'class':'lemon--h3__373c0__sQmiG heading--h3__373c0__1n4Of alternate__373c0__1uacp'})
        number_sequence = base.text[0]
        if int(number_sequence) in (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9):
            try:
                info_scraped['Restaurant_Name'] = data.find('h3',{'class':'lemon--h3__373c0__sQmiG heading--h3__373c0__1n4Of alternate__373c0__1uacp'}).find('a',{'class':'lemon--a__373c0__IEZFH link__373c0__29943 link-color--blue-dark__373c0__1mhJo link-size--inherit__373c0__2JXk5'}).text
            except:
                print(None)
            try:
                info_scraped['Phone_Number'] = data.find('div',{'class':'lemon--div__373c0__1mboc container__373c0__19wDx u-padding-l2 border-color--default__373c0__2oFDT text-align--right__373c0__3fmmn'}).find('p',{'class':'lemon--p__373c0__3Qnnj text__373c0__2pB8f text-color--normal__373c0__K_MKN text-align--right__373c0__3ARv7'}).text
            except:
                print(None)
            try:
                info_scraped['Address'] = data.find('div',{'class':'lemon--div__373c0__1mboc container__373c0__19wDx u-padding-l2 border-color--default__373c0__2oFDT text-align--right__373c0__3fmmn'}).find('span',{'class':'lemon--span__373c0__3997G'}).text
            except:
                print(None)
            try:
                info_scraped['States'] = data.find('div',{'class':'lemon--div__373c0__1mboc container__373c0__19wDx u-padding-l2 border-color--default__373c0__2oFDT text-align--right__373c0__3fmmn'}).find('div',{'class':'lemon--div__373c0__1mboc display--inline-block__373c0__2de_K border-color--default__373c0__2oFDT'}).text
            except:
                print(None)
            try:
                info_scraped['Category'] = data.find('div',{'class':'lemon--div__373c0__1mboc largerScrollablePhotos__373c0__3FEIJ arrange__373c0__UHqhV border-color--default__373c0__2oFDT'}).find('div',{'class':'lemon--div__373c0__1mboc mainAttributes__373c0__1r0QA arrange-unit__373c0__1piwO arrange-unit-fill__373c0__17z0h border-color--default__373c0__2oFDT'}).find('div',{'class':'lemon--div__373c0__1mboc priceCategory__373c0__3zW0R border-color--default__373c0__2oFDT'}).find('span',{'class':'lemon--span__373c0__3997G display--inline__373c0__1DbOG border-color--default__373c0__2oFDT'}).text
            except:
                print(None)
            final_data.append(info_scraped)
    except:
        continue
        
driver.find_element_by_xpath('''/html/body/div[1]/div[4]/div/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[3]/span/a/div''').click()
time.sleep(10)
yelp_page_source2 = driver.page_source

driver.find_element_by_xpath('''/html/body/div[1]/div[4]/div/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[4]/span/a/div''').click()
time.sleep(10)
yelp_page_source3 = driver.page_source

driver.find_element_by_xpath('''/html/body/div[1]/div[4]/div/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[5]/span/a/div''').click()
time.sleep(10)
yelp_page_source4 = driver.page_source

driver.find_element_by_xpath('''/html/body/div[1]/div[4]/div/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[6]/span/a/div''').click()
time.sleep(10)
yelp_page_source5 = driver.page_source

driver.find_element_by_xpath('''/html/body/div[1]/div[4]/div/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[7]/span/a/div''').click()
time.sleep(10)
yelp_page_source6 = driver.page_source

driver.find_element_by_xpath('''/html/body/div[1]/div[4]/div/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[8]/span/a/div''').click()
time.sleep(10)
yelp_page_source7 = driver.page_source

driver.find_element_by_xpath('''/html/body/div[1]/div[4]/div/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[9]/span/a/div''').click()
time.sleep(10)
yelp_page_source8 = driver.page_source
      


df = pandas.DataFrame(final_data)
df.index += 1
df = df[['Restaurant_Name', 'Phone_Number', 'Address', 'States', 'Category']]
pandas.set_option('display.max_rows', 9999999)
df.to_csv('yelp_info.csv')
```

Comment: `final_data` is empty after the loop